# NodeJS listening on HTTP and HTTPS for one single domain name

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-web-services, express, https

I use express and a server cloud on AWS (Amazon Web Server) and a DNS "mydomain.com".

Question: how can I avoid my users to have to writing in the Browser-URL: http://mydomain.com:4000 and https://mydomain.com:3000

This is my code:

sudo node app.js

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(4000, function() {
        console.log('Express HTTP server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
var server = https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('Express HTTPS server listening on port 3000');
});

// redirect all http requests to https
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect(['https://mydomain.com', req.url].join(''));
  }
  next();
});
```

I want my user to be able to write my domain name using http and https with no port numbers. I already have a SSL certificate and everything is working fine, but I haven't been able remove the port-numbers and use both: https and http.

Any idea? please :)

I use MEAN stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, )

Comment: Aside from the non-default port issue that is the subject of my answer, you have a problem in your code where you're creating 2 server objects but assigning both of the to the one variable.  If you want to be able to access both servers in your code you'll need 2 different variables.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, can you please give me a code example? please

Comment: @AndrewCooper, my app is really extensive and if I use two apps I will have to duplicate all my code, but how can I use two server objects and two apps without duplicate my code?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do that is to use the default ports for the protocols.  That is, Port 80 for HTTP and Port 443 for HTTPS.

If you don't use the default protocol ports then the only way for the browser (or whatever client the users are using) to determine which port to connect to is for the user to specify it in the URL.

**Edit** - To address your comment above about different server objects

In the code in your question you create an HTTP server and then use the variable `server` to hold a reference to the object.  You then create an HTTPS server and assign it to the same variable.  If you use the `server` variable later in your code then you'll be dealing with the HTTPS server object, but will have no way to reference the HTTP server object.

To fix this, just use two different variables to hold the object references.

```
var httpServer = http.createServer ....
var httpsServer = https.createServer ....
```

Comment: As sson as I use the default ports: 80 and 443, then I get this error: "listen EADDRINUSE". is there any option with iptables?

Comment: Sure.  You could have iptables redirect incoming connections to port 443 to port 3000, but then why would you not just listen on port 443 in the first place?

Comment: As sson as I use the default ports: 80 and 443, then I get this error: "listen EADDRINUSE".

Comment: Sounds like something might already be listening on one/both of those ports.

Comment: No, nothing is listening on port 80 and 443, I just double check with lsof -i | grep 443 and lsof -i | grep 80

Comment: Try `netstat -punta | grep 80`

Comment: ... or `lsof -i -P | grep 80`

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. When I do `netstat -punta | grep 80` then I get: `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN - `. What does that mean? should I change the config of the EC2 server?

Comment: It means something is listening on port 80.  You'll need to work out what it is.  Does `lsof -i -P` help?

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS REALLY USELESS AS THE PORT 80 AND 443 IS ALWAYS RESERVE FOR THE OPERATIVE SYSTEM.

Comment: @lito - Which operating system?  Those ports are not reserved in any general purpose operating system that I know of.  If they were there'd be no way to stand up a standard web server.  If they really are reserved in the OS you're using then there's no way to do want you want without putting a separate proxy machine in front of your server to do the port translation - or maybe some iptables rules that intercept the traffic at the IP layer.